# Express API timeout despite success callback

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, parse-server

I have an express API:

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post("/adapter/mail", function(request, response) {

    var body = request.body;
    var id = body.id;
    var params = {id: id};

    Parse.Cloud.run("email", params, {
        success: function(e) {
            console.log("api: success");
            respone.status(200).send("e");
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log("api: error: " + JSON.stringify(e));
            response.status(500).send(e);
        }
    });
});
```

Calling the API calls the Parse Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("email", function(request, response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));
    response.success("ok");
});
```

In the console I see that `console.log("api: success");` gets executed correctly, but the API request does not end, it times out despite the successful callback.

When Cloud Code returns `response.error("error");` instead of `response.success("ok");` the request does not timeout but ends immediately.

Why does the request time out on success?

Comment: There's a typo in your code `respone.status(200).send("e");` is missing an 's' in 'response'.

Comment: @JulianGoacher Thanks, that solved it. Took me 1h, time to sleep I guess :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing an "s" on your callback

respon"s"e.status(200).send("e");